# Handling an image download popup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm trying to download an image using Python's Mechanize, and that's an easy thing to do with urlretrieve, however this image's 'src' attribute holds a url which initiates a download popup. There doesn't seem to be a url that points to the image.

I'm using Python Mechanize, but my research tells me that there's no way to handle the pop up in Mechanize, and I would have to use something like Selenium. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Selenium seems to be the case for this. The following code shows how to deal with pop-up's.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

try:
    alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    # do something with alert, like download the content
    alert.dismiss()
 except:
    pass
```